# Find power series of $\frac{z^2}{2-z}$ about $z=3$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

So I need to find power series of $\frac{z^2}{2-z}$ about $z=3$. Here's what I have so far

$$\frac{z^2}{2-z}=\frac{-z^2}{1+(z-3)}$$

Where

$$\frac{1}{1+(z-3)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(z-3)^n$$

Now so I just multiply through by a $-z^2$ term and thats it?

Comment: $z^2$ is $(z-3)^2+6(z-3)+9$. I suggest you consider using this.

Comment: @MH.Lee do I multiply this through my power series?

Comment: Yes, that is the fastest method, I think.

Comment: When you have a rational function, it is convenient to compute its [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition). In this case you only need to do [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division), to get $\frac{z^2}{2-z}=-z-2+\frac{4}{2-z}$. Next write them in powers of $z-3$, which gives $-1-(z-3)-4\frac{1}{1-(-(z-3))}$. Finally, use that $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$, with $x=z-3$.

Comment: So Ill have two terms then $4$ times the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z-3)^n$? @user85667

Comment: @MH.Lee How would you multiply the two together when the series is infinite?

Comment: Note the $-$ sign in the $-(z-3)$. So, it would be the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(z-3)^n$. This is the one that gets multiplied by $4$.

Comment: But $-1 - (-3)= +2$ not $-2$ @user85667

Comment: I could have made a mistake with the signs. Note there is also a $-$ in front of the $4$.

Comment: @user85667  but that $-4$ is being multiplied by the fraction, it cannot be combined with the constant terms..

Comment: @user85667 sorry I'm still a bit stuck lol could you help me out plz

Comment: Just check if $-5-(z-3)-4\frac{1}{1-(-(z-3))}$ is equal to $\frac{z^2}{2-z}$

Comment: ok, $-5$ is what I got too! sweet, thanks! @user85667